# Paho: Parallel Connection Creation leads to Connection Dropdown

Tags: java, mqtt, paho

I am using the JAVA `paho` client and a [mosquitto mqtt broker](https://mosquitto.org/) 1.6.7.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.paho</groupId>
    <artifactId>org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I am subscribing to multiple topics, so I created a class which looks like the following:

```
private String topic = "";
private MqttClient client = null;

public MqttEndpoint(String topic) throws InterruptedException {
    this.topic = topic;
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                client = getNewClient();
                client.setCallback(new Callback());                 
                client.subscribe(topic);

                //isInitialized=true;
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
        }
    }.start();
}
```

My code in my main class looks like the following:

```
new MqttEndpoint("abc/def");
new MqttEndpoint("abc/def2");
...
```

I created the Thread for the connection in order to avoid long connection times. My Problem: With this approach I get (not always, but sometimes) a connection lost error (32109):

```
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:190)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.base/java.io.DataInputStream.readByte(DataInputStream.java:272)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.wire.MqttInputStream.readMqttWireMessage(MqttInputStream.java:92)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:137)
    ... 1 more
```

`getNewClient` just returns a new client:

```
public static MqttClient getNewClient(){
        MqttClient client = null;
        try {
            String id=MqttClient.generateClientId();
            client = new MqttClient("tcp://localhost", id,new MemoryPersistence() );
            MqttConnectOptions options = new MqttConnectOptions();
            options.setMaxInflight(8000);
           options.setAutomaticReconnect(true);
            client.connect(options);
        } catch (MqttException exception) {
            if (exception.getCause() instanceof InterruptedException) {
                throw (InterruptedException) exception.getCause();
            }
        }

        return client;
}
```

I haven't received this error if I remove the thread:

```
public MqttEndpoint(String topic) throws InterruptedException {
    this.topic = topic;

            try {
                client = getNewClient();
                client.setCallback(new Callback());                 
                client.subscribe(topic);
                LOGGER.info("subscribed to "+ topic);

                //isInitialized=true;
            } catch (MqttException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }               
}
```

What do I wrong?

EDIT:
I am using QoS 1 for publishing messages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem is the following line:

```
String id=MqttClient.generateClientId();
```

I generates a client id based on user name and system time. If you create multiple clients simultaneously then the probability of a id chrash increases dramatically which leads to the connection lost errors....

Comment: There is no need to create multiple client to subscribe to multiple topics. A client can call `client.subscribe()` multiple times. You just need to add a test in the callback to check which topic

Comment: Yes, but then I have to check in the callback which topic fired....

Comment: No you don't, Look at the other versions of the `subscribe ()` one of them takes an array of topics and an array of callbacks

Comment: And even if you don't the overheated of a switch statement is easy well than a while extra client

Comment: you are right, that makes more sense and reduces the effort +1